# Laravel detect internal route dispatch

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm calling some internal methods from within a controller to another route. In that route, I need to detect whether or not the request was made from within my own calls or whether or not it was made over HTTP (like a web browser).

For example, my code might say:

```
$Request = Request::create("some-route");
$Response = Route::dispatch($Request)->getContent();
```

Within my 'some-route' action, I need to know whether the request was called internally or externally

```
//Within my 'some-route' method

if(Request::isInternal(){
  //How do I perform this check?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to [flash some session data](http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data) and then check whether it exists (and is the expected value) on the receiving end?